# Mapping a graph to a line

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

What does it exactly mean when a graph is mapped to a line in the plane? We have a graph where there is a vertex $v$ of degree 3 or more, and it is stated that if this vertex is mapped to a line in the plane with all of its neighboring vertices, then at least one of the faces adjacent to $v$ is not a triangle (geometrically speaking).

We define a triangle in a geometric manner i.e. a face of a drawing of a graph is a triangle if the edges connecting the vertices form a triangle.

Comment: Can you give some more context?

Comment: ...is *this* what you're reading? https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-03841-4_11

Comment: I was not (but something based on this apparently), but this paper clears this right up. Thanks.